# How to detect removed item in $scope.$watch?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-digest

Is it any way to detect removed or added item via $scope.$watch?

Please, see the example below:

```
var data = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}];

$scope.$watch(function () {return data}, function (newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log(newValue, oldValue);
    // I want to detect removing or adding here:
    // var removedItem = ...?
    // var addedItem = ...?
}, true)

data.push({id: 4});
data.splice(0, 1);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works fine for me

```
x = []

$rootScope.$watch((-> x), (newValue, oldValue) ->

    changed = newValue.filter((item, index) ->
        return oldValue[index] and angular.equals(item, oldValue[index]) is no
    )
    added = newValue.filter((item, index) ->
        return not oldValue[index]
    )
    removed = oldValue.filter((item, index) ->
        return not newValue[index]
    )
    console.log('x', changed, added, removed)
, yes)
```

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS is dirtychecking this collection, and since you are doing it so quickly, your console log won't even run until that *second* `.splice()` change.

Try this, add a `$timeout(function () { }` and put your `.splice()` code there, and now notice the console.log things.

For example:

```
// Make sure to add the $timeout dependency
$timeout(function () {
    data.splice(0, 1);
}, 1000);
```

Now you'll be able to save things in those variables you made and notice if there are any differences.

Here's a jsfiddle for reference, you can see the differences in the objects.
**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wLdg2wma/)**

Answer (score 0):

There is not direct way to achieve this. Probably you can use the below for the result.

//To display the newValue.
var diff = $(newValue).not(oldValue).get();

//To display the oldValue.
var diff = $(oldValue).not(newValue).get();

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`$watchCollection`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection).

From the docs:

> The [...] collection is observed via standard `$watch` operation and is examined on every call to `$digest()` to see if any items have been added, removed, or moved.

Comment: How I can get the removed item?